# MySql using interval with a list of dates

Tags: mysql, sql, intervals

I'm willing to fetch all the dates that are listed in the list reducing 1 day
I'm trying something like that:

```
select date
from MyTable
where date in ('2022-03-22', '2022-03-18', '2022-03-11') - interval 1 day
```

I wish to receive:

'2022-03-21', '2022-03-17', '2022-03-10'

Comment: What are `list` you are referring to here?

Comment: if it worked for you don't forget to give it a positive vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with intervals.

**Here is a link to how it works :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/48

```
SELECT ADDDATE("2022-03-22", INTERVAL -1 DAY);
SELECT ADDDATE("2022-03-18", INTERVAL -1 DAY);
SELECT ADDDATE("2022-03-11", INTERVAL -1 DAY);
```

**You can also do it with a concat for example :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/49

```
SELECT CONCAT(ADDDATE("2022-03-22", INTERVAL -1 DAY),' | ',
              ADDDATE("2022-03-18", INTERVAL -1 DAY),' | ',
              ADDDATE("2022-03-11", INTERVAL -1 DAY));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add 1 day to the `date` column's value to compare it against the `IN` list:

```
SELECT date
FROM MyTable
WHERE date + INTERVAL 1 DAY IN ('2022-03-22', '2022-03-18', '2022-03-11');
```